# Single dimensional array address

Tags: c, arrays

```
char arr[10]="hello";
```

I guess `&arr` in this array is of type `char(*)[10]`.
If I am right, what is the type of `*(&arr)`? Is it of type base address or address to first element in array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given:

```
char arr[10];
```

as you say, `&arr` is of type `char (*)[10]`.  Of itself, `*(&arr)` is of type `char [10]`, but in most contexts (other than `sizeof()`) it will become `char *` when it is used.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char arr[10] = "hello";

    printf("arr[10]         = \"%s\"\n", arr);
    printf("arr             = %p\n", arr);
    printf("&arr            = %p\n", &arr);
    printf("*(&arr)         = %p\n", *(&arr));
    printf("sizeof(*(&arr)) = %zu\n", sizeof(*(&arr)));
    printf("arr+1           = %p\n", arr+1);
    printf("&arr+1          = %p\n", &arr+1);
    printf("*(&arr)         = \"%s\"\n", *(&arr));
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output (GCC 4.7.1, Mac OS X 10.8.3):

```
arr[10]         = "hello"
arr             = 0x7fff4ff15500
&arr            = 0x7fff4ff15500
*(&arr)         = 0x7fff4ff15500
sizeof(*(&arr)) = 10
arr+1           = 0x7fff4ff15501
&arr+1          = 0x7fff4ff1550a
*(&arr)         = "hello"
```

Note that although the values of `arr` and `&arr` are the same, the types are different.  This is most clearly demonstrated by the `arr+1` and `&arr+1` lines.  As you can see, incrementing `&arr` by one adds the sizeof of the object it points at (a `char [10]`) to the address.

You can extend the example to add other values as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks. So what is the type of base address?? is it char *?

Comment: The term 'base address' isn't clearly defined.  However, the type of the expression `arr` is `char [10]` but becomes `char *` in most contexts — the exception being `sizeof()` where it remains `char [10]` so `sizeof(arr)` is 10.

Answer (score 4):

The expression `*(&arr)` is the same type as `arr`. The dereference and address-of operators cancel out each other out.

You use the address-of operator `&` to get the address, i.e. get a pointer. You use the dereference operator `*` to get the value of what a pointer points to. So using both of them like that doesn't make any sense in that context.

Answer (score 2):

`*(&arr)` is of type base address, where as `*(&arr[0])` is the first element in the array.

Answer (score 2):

```
   char arr[10];
```

`arr` has type "array of 10 chars" and `&arr` is "pointer to array of 10 chars." ,  `*(&arr)` is the same as `arr`, and has the same type, i.e, base address.

`&arr[0]` will yield a pointer that points to the first element address.

Answer (score 0):

a, *(&a), &a[0] are same (base address of array a/ address of the first element of array a).